# Leader Election in Raft

Tags: distributed-system, consensus, raft

I'm Implementing a basic Raft Consensus Algorithm. Basically, I've few question regarding leader election in raft.

1. When Candidate send RequestVote rpc to other server, As prev term leader see term of RequestVote rpc is greater than it current term, prev term leader changes its state to follower state. but if no candidate win election in that term. then their will be no leader for time being. so how to handle the client request if came as their is no leader for time being.
2. suppose the split-brain happen in raft, and one server got disconnect from the other server(i.e Network Issue).leader and other server doesn't have any communication to to faulty server. as the election timeout occure on faulty server it try out leader election but fails to connect with other server and retry again, and it's term went much ahead from the other server.

```
Intial state when split brain happen

leader and other server term: 2
faulty server term: 2

As faulty server try out leader election

leader and other server term: 2
faulty server term: 12
```

Now suppose the connection between faulty and other server is established. how handle such situation to get faulty server upto date with leader.

Answer (score 0):

1.Client requests will not be accepted until the  leader election successful

2.Faulty server will start a new leader election,Other servers find that larger term will change their status to followers and update their term.
However, the faulty server does not have the latest data, so it will  election fail. Other server will try new leader election after the election timeout until the election is successful.

Finally the servers term maybe like this:

faulty server term: 14

other server term: 14

You also can use prevote algorithm optimizes this situation.